# SwiftUI `searchable` results in jumpy animation when used with `ScrollView`

Tags: ios, swiftui

When putting a `ScrollView` inside a `NavigationView`, that uses the `searchable` view modifier, focusing and unfocusing the search bar causes the `ScrollView` to jump immediately instead of smoothly animating as a `List` view would do.

[image: recording showing the jumpy animation]

The code below produces the behaviour in the GIF above.

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    @State
    private var term = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Text("Bar")
                    Text("Baz")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Foo")
        }
        .searchable(text: $term)
    }
}
```

This seems like a SwiftUI bug to me? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you mean `searchable` on the title instead of `scrollable`?